# Is there any viable DIY method of fusing 2 (or any amount of) cables together to form ribbon cable?

Tags: cables, bus

By "bus cable" I mean something like this:
[image]

I guess glue would not work, as you would need to dose microscopic amounts of it all they way through cable for it to not look ugly glue blob.

I guess heating wires to around their melting point with heatgun and then squeezing together might connect them, but it will probably be ugly too...

Ideally, one would need some thin heatwire that will melt just one side of 2 wires, and then pass them trough it and immediately close them together, so they fuse. This will work best but requires special machine to be built which could be complicated and costly... Maybe that's how they do it in factories?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with that? The normal way which everyone does this is to twist the wires around each other. Which is also much better for EMC than the cable in your pic, because you end up with twisted pair.

Comment: @Lundin Well, it will untwist? Unless again, you apply huge amounts of glue in some places. Or use giant and excessive amounts of heat shrinks or isolating tape... Also if you need to do more than 2 cables the "twist" will become a real mess!

Comment: You want to join two of these cables together end to end? Or something else? Please explain **exactly** what it is you want to do and why.

Comment: This question is terribly lacking in intent and clarity. Terminology: 2 wires does not form a bus. 2 wires is just 2 wires. A bus can be run on two wires, however, but 2 wires is not a bus. A bus is so much more. To twist wires, use a hand drill at one end and a vise at the other end. Any number of wires. I don't know why you think they would untwist without glue. Have you ever held wire in your hands before? Have ever used a twist tie to tie a bag? They aren't pieces of string.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer No they won't untwist, it's metal, not shoelaces. Bend it and it stays. See the pictures in the posted answer. That's how everyone who works with electronics do it.

Comment: I don't get if he want to splice two cables or doing some kind of cable bundle. Need more explanation on what he want to do

Comment: 2 layers of sellotape...?

Comment: If they only need to be held next to each other tidily, you could use cable combs.

Comment: .. why not just buy ribbon cable?

Answer (score 8):

You can either:

- Twist the cables together, for example with a drill, twisted enough they won't come apart. Check some youtube videos. That is the best because for differential buses like CAN, RS485, it negates EMI, if twisted by pair.

[image]

- You can braid them:

[image]

- Use some thermal shrinking tube.
- Use some cable sleeves like those:

[image]

Glue is a bad idea, it probably won't stick or may chemically react over time.

Comment: Twisting/Braiding a cable also wastes some of it's length. Sheath cables or super long shrinking tubes might be a good idea, but again, this are too costly.

Comment: Unless you are running intercontinental cables, I doubt 5-10% added cable length would be of any cost concern to any design. Glue would certainly be more expensive. As for cable sleeves, they cost like 0.1$ per foot.

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use a non-corrosive silicone overmold (often clear in color). This is possible to do in small quantities. Here is a promotional brochure page from a company named Circoil:

[image]

The method on the right (which they contrast their products with) is suitable for small quantities. Do **not** attempt this with acetic acid cured silicone as commonly used for construction etc. Use only electronic grade silicone. The mold could be as simple as a trough with a spray of mold release.

Some flat cables are extruded as one piece (typically the ones that cannot be easily split without cutting and are one color, possibly with markings added), the multicolor wires you show are bonded after the individual wires are extruded. The latter process is fussy and unsuitable for small quantities, as is the extrusion method which requires a substantial production line.